# Animate a sequantial AnimatorSet inside a playTogether AnimatorSet in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am trying to chain a set of animations using AnimatorSets.

I have something like this:

```
AnimatorSet sequentialSet = new AnimatorSet();
sequentialSet.playSequentially(animOne, animTwo, animThree);

AnimatorSet togetherSet = new AnimatorSet();
togetherSet.playTogether(sequentialSet, animFour, animFive);
togetherSet.setDuration(ANIM_TIMEOUT);
togetherSet.start();
```

However, what happens is, animOne animates together with animFour and animFive and then animations animTwo followed by animThree happen. Has anyone seen this before and is there a way to make animations animOne, animTwo, animThree execute during the same time as animFour and animFive?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that `togetherSet.setDuration(ANIM_TIMEOUT)` was overriding the duration for all of the animations within it. My solution is to set duration individually for each animation and to not set it on the set itself.